# Get Custom JSON from Stack Settings in AWS OpsWorks with Chef 12

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, chef-infra

I'm currently working on the OpsWorks stacks with Chef 12, writing my own deploying recipes. Is there any possibilities to get the content of the field "Custom JSON" in Stack Settings?

Cheers,
xiGUAwanOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that data gets set as node attributes, so you can access it as per normal via the `node` object.

Comment: Your edit has been rejected by the SO reviewers as that is not the correct API. You can find more info about Chef basics in our tutorial at https://learn.chef.io