# Migrating from AWS Opsworks Stacks Chef 11 to Chef 12 - stack attributes question

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

2 questions.  I'm striking out on the AWS docs and forum threads here...

When you migrate to opsworks stacks chef12 attributes is no longer available from the node object

> "Stack settings are no longer available as Chef attributes, so stack
>   settings can no longer be accessed through the Chef node object. For
>   more information, see the AWS OpsWorks Stacks Data Bag Reference."
>   as per the official docs.

The problem is.  How can i get at those top level attributes stored in the layers-general settings-custom json?  I know these get passed to the instance b/c i can find that json in /var/chef/runs/{randomstring}/attrib.json  BUT that is a level above the databags directory. i can't see anyway to access that as a variable in opsworks/chef.

Second question, is there any way to access that random chef run directory as a variable in opsworks/chef? if so I can go grab that data easily.

I have seen this:
[Get Custom JSON from Stack Settings in AWS OpsWorks with Chef 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707501/get-custom-json-from-stack-settings-in-aws-opsworks-with-chef-12) 
but based on my experimenting I can't seem to access those #{node... values in chef12 opsworks stacks.

@coderanger you are probably my only hope here.

ps. is it just me or is opsworks TERRIBLE.
that is all.

Answer (score 0):

OK. after continuing to dig - apparently despite what the official Docs say in one place - you CAN still access that top level custom JSON with the original syntax #{node['whateveryourkeyis']} ...etc.  The errors I was getting when trying that turned out to be unrelated so, there you go, fwiw you can sill grab that custom json but not the other attributes of applications - those have moved on to the databags.

oh, and to answer the other question - yes i'm still pretty sure opsworks IS terrible. change my mind.